# Is there a way to get the number of Facebook friends without fetching the array of friends?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently fetching the full list of friends and getting the size of the array. Looking for a quicker way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use FQL to fetch the list of friend uids which would be slightly lighter weight than fetching the full friend list via the graph api objects.